# Erro no netfx (MSBUILD) ao buildar projeto

Tags: visual-studio, build, msbuild

Ao tentar buildar meu projeto estou tomando esse erro:

```
> An attempt was made to load an assembly with an incorrect format:
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\net461\ref\netfx.force.conflicts.dll.
```

Obs:

Este projeto e compartilhado dentro da empresa onde varios outros devs buildam normalmente o memso.

Esta compartilhado no TFS.

Não foi feita alteração no mesmo.

Com algumas pesquisas vi que pode estar relacionado a alguma coisa com as TAG's  de 64x/86x, mas olhei sobre e não consegui prosseguir com o problema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O erro foi corrigido atualizando a versao do meu Visual Studio (2017).